# Как поменять размер изображения в админке WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Я просматриваю код на своём сайте, ищу наподобие этого: `width="308" height="279"`, но этого там наверное, нет и в помине. Пытался искать в коде по-другому: `274*63` - но ничего такого в коде тоже нет. Каким же образом у WordPress прописан в админке размер изображения?

Comment: Люди соглашусь в html всё гораздо проще !!!!

Comment: Ну это размер этого изображения logo-login.png в WordPredss

Comment: Все это в стилях прописано

Comment: Стили css ? В каком файле ?

Comment: Уточните: размер какого изображения? — вставленного в пост, в списке Медиафайлов?

Comment: Я уточнил читай внимательно (((в коде 274*63))))

Comment: Размер изображение указан php кодом - его и меняйте

Comment: Сожалею сударь но это не ответ .... В каком php файле wordpress указан размер изображения ?

Comment: Посмотрите по коду, какой у него класс, какой стиль, какие атрибуты, чем дышит это изображение, все находится!

Answer (score 1):

Размеры миниатюр задаются в Настройки → Медиафайлы. Но тема может использовать что-то своё.